# "Read Timed Out" error with Google Drive API Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an Android application in which I have integrated `Google Drive REST API` to upload files. I am trying to upload files with `size in 1-2 GB`.

I am getting `"Read Timed Out"` error after the upload process runs for sometime.

My Code:

```
MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener(this.dialog));
uploader.setChunkSize(512*1024); //set chunk size to 512KB to avoid timeout error
insert.setFields("id").execute();
```

I have following questions:

1. What are the possible reasons for this type of error?
2. Can slow internet connection speed cause this type of error?
3. What are the best practices to overcome the issue or show appropriate error message?

Thank you.

Comment: Read timed out is not a google drive error that I am aware of. I think that you should post the full error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried to upload the 2GB file with other internet connection having larger upload speed and the file was successfully uploaded with out the "time out" error. Hence, I think this could be issue related internet bandwidth.

Comment: @DaImTo Do you have any thoughts about what could be the best coding practices to handle such issues?